# Positive semidefiniteness of submatrix of positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Assume $A$ is a real symmetric positive semidefinite $k\times k$ matrix. Denote by $A^{(a:b,c:d)}$ the submatrix of $A$ obtained by keeping only the rows between $a$ and $b$, and columns between $c$ and $d$. Now define the $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ matrix defined by

$ \tilde{A} = A^{(1:k-1,1:k-1)} - \bigg(A^{(1:k-1,k)}(A^{(k,k)})^{-1}\bigg)A^{(k,k)}\bigg(A^{(1:k-1,k)}(A^{(k,k)})^{-1}\bigg)^{\prime} $.

I'm pretty sure that this matrix is positive semidefinite, but I need some to help to verify that claim rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing
$$
A = \pmatrix{ A_1 & a \\ a^T & c}
$$
we have
$$
\tilde A = A_1 - aa^T c^{-1}.
$$
Let $x\in \mathbb R^{k-1}$. Then
$$
x^T\tilde Ax = x^TA_1x - (x^Ta)(a^Tx) c^{-1}.
$$
We want to use the matrix $A$, so let me augment $x$ by a real number $b$ to obtain
$$
0\le \pmatrix{x \\ b }^TA\pmatrix{x \\ b } 
= x^TA_1x + 2b a^Tx + b ^2c.
$$
Setting $b=-c^{-1} a^Tx$ yields
$$
0\le \pmatrix{x \\ -c^{-1} a^Tx }^TA\pmatrix{x \\ -c^{-1} a^Tx }=x^TA_1x - (x^Ta)(a^Tx) c^{-1},
$$
which shows positive semidefinitness.